# Send iPA using XCode 7

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, xcode7, ipa

I have downloaded XCode 7 recently and I have installed app in my iPhone as well using my Apple ID. I don't have Apple developer programmer $99 account. I wanted to send my iPA to Client to test the App in his iPhone. 
Client is based in out of country. Can I send the build to client as well in Xcode 7 without creating $99 account. if Yes what would I do to achieve it? Please guide if someone know about it.
Thank you.

Comment: With Xcode 7, everyone can run and test their own app on a device - for free. But to distribute .ipa, you still need a dev account.

Comment: Yes. I need to create account to send an .ipa to client. Thanks Wang.